# angular app prefetch calls to slim 3 api

Tags: angular, slim-3

I've been working on an app made with angular 4 (via angular cli) which calls an API made with slim 3. How do i manage prefetch calls when adding headers to api request?
At the moment, for each route, I add an 'options' route which just return the response, but it seems a bad way to do it:

```
$app->options('/users', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
$app->post('/users', 'MyController');
```

Is there a neater way to do it?

EDIT: I found an answer [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1700) and did

```
$app->options('/[{path:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
```